# Allocating memory for Heap with mallocs

Tags: c

I'm having problems declaring a new heap, empty, with max size "capacity".

Heap struct:

```
typedef struct {
    /* number of elements on vector */
    int size;
    /* vector max size */
    int capacity;
    /*vector of pointers for elements*/
    element_t** elements;
} heap;
```

Element_t struct:

```
typedef struct element_
{
    char nameItem[100];
    char expirationDate[11];
    int qty;
    int sellRate;
    float priorityVal;
} element_t;
```

The function that I need to create the heap is declared like that, where the argument capacity is the heap capacity.

```
heap* new_heap(int capacity){
```

Function that insert elements in Heap:

```
int heap_insert(heap *h, element_t* elem)
{
    element_t * aux;
    int i;
    //gilc
    if(!h) return 0;
    /* if heap is full, dont insert element */
    if (h->size >= h->capacity)
        return 0;

    if (!elem)
        return 0;

    /* insert element in the end of the heap */
    h->size++;
    i = h->size;
    h->elements[i] = elem;

    /* while element has more prioritary than his father, trade them */
    while (i != ROOT && bigger_than(h->elements[i], h->elements[FATHER(i)]))
    {
        aux = h->elements[FATHER(i)];
        h->elements[FATHER(i)] = h->elements[i];
        h->elements[i] = aux;
        i = FATHER(i);
    }
    return 1;

    //Default
    return 0;
}
```

FATHER and ROOT is defined like that (I don't understand what that means, was pre-defined for the project too)

```
#define FATHER(x)       (x/2)
#define ROOT        (1)
```

and `bigger_than` like this:

```
int bigger_than(element_t* e1, element_t* e2)
{
    if (e1 == NULL || e2 == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return e1->priorityVal > e2->priorityVal;
}
```

What malloc calls do I need to use? The function new_heap must allocate all memory necessary for the number of elements specified as argument capacity.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more information: Do you expect function `new_heap` to allocate all memory necessary for the number of elements specified as argument `capacity`? Are you required to use a vector of pointers `element_t **elements`? Otherwise I would suggest to use a simple pointer `element_t *elements` and use it as a dynamically allocated array of size `int capacity` instead.

Comment: Edited, what u mean by a vector of pointers element_t **elements?

Comment: @RicardoSilva my answer should work for you after your edit.

Comment: @RicardoSilva I just cited the comment `/*vector of pointers for elements*/` from your code. With a "vector of pointers" you would need memory for an array of pointers **and** memory for all elements where the pointers should point to. You would either have to allocate `capacity` times the memory for one single `element_t` or an array that can hold `capacity` elements of `element_t`. And you would have to assign the correct addresses to all the pointers in the pointers array.

Comment: I thought about using element_t *elements but this is a school project and I can't change how the structure is declared...

Comment: @RicardoSilva Then make clear **in your question** when and how you want all memory to be allocated: There are 3 types of memory: The structure of type `heap`, the array of pointers as its element `element_t** elements;` and either an array of `element_t` structures or individual `element_t` structures.

Comment: I would want all to be allocated in the new_heap function if it was possible

Answer (score 1):

```
heap *new_heap(int capacity) {
    heap *h = malloc(sizeof(heap));
    h->size = 0;
    h->capacity = capacity;
    h->elements = malloc(capacity * sizeof(element_t *));
    return h;
}
```

The first malloc will make enough space for your heap structure. The second is for "vector" (as you called it) of pointers to elements, since these need to be stored in a separate spot in memory (based on your declaration of `heap`). Together, this allocates all the memory you need for the heap. I'm assuming you'll also have a `new_element` function that will handle allocating the memory for an individual element for you whenever you want to add something to the `heap`.

Comment: @Bodo yes. I'm assuming that when he adds elements to the heap, he will have already allocated the memory for them. Are you suggesting I should allocate memory for each of the elements here, and then alter those in-place when I want to add an element?

Comment: What should I declare to allocate the memory for the actual element_t structures? Because I have already a pre-declared function gave on the project to insert the elements and these function don't allocate the memory necessary when adding an element

Comment: @RicardoSilva In your question you should show the function that inserts an element.

Comment: @RicardoSilva if this answer solved your problem, you can accept it by checking the grey checkmark to the left of it.